# Windows phone: cannot connect to a computer using socket

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone, firewall

Situation: there are two programs - client and server.
Server is working on my computer, client program is working on windows phone.
Server is listening for incoming connections ant receive data. Windows phone creates a socket(tcp connection) and sends data.

If I connect win-phone to my computer using USB cable, all works: connection establishes and data is transferring.
But when I create an "infrastructure-network" using the program "connectify", or connect to real wi-fi router (computer and win-phone both are connected to the same network) it is not working. I disabled windows firewall, but it is still not working.
How can it be explained? Where is the problem?

Comment: Too few details. What are IP addresses? What's the wifi setup? etc.

Comment: ip addresses are 192.168.152.101 (phone) and 192.168.152.101 (computer).

Comment: Could you elaborate on "doesn't work?" What kind of errors or exceptions are you getting?

Comment: That's already wrong - how do you expect two network nodes to communicate when they have exact same address?

Comment: sorry, that was an error, when i copied an address. computer has address: 192.168.152.1

Comment: Do yo have a ping command on the windows phone? If so see if you can ping the desktop ip from the windows phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in ip address string in python server code.
I used "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" :(